# SubmitChanges() not updating the database

Tags: c#, linq

I am an old hand at ADO.NET but new to linq. I have written the below function to change one column of int in the database to a new value. The query part works fine, but after me updating the KeyStates in the database doesn't seem to work. Nothing changes. No errors, but also no update.

```
    public static void UpdateKeySetToDatabase(IChangeTrackableAsSet set, 
        int tableId, State newState)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var c = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                c.Open();

                List<int> keyList = set.trackedKeys.Select(k => k.KeyId).ToList();

                DataContext dc = new DataContext(c);                      
                Table<TrackedKey> tableKeys = dc.GetTable<TrackedKey>();

                var KeyStates =
                    from k in tableKeys
                    where (keyList.Contains(k.KeyId) && k.TableId == tableId)
                    select k;


                foreach (var k in KeyStates)
                {

                    EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"Key {k.ShowKeyAsJson()}");
                    k.StatusOfKey = (int)newState;
                    EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"New Key {k.ShowKeyAsJson()}");
                };

                tableKeys.Context.SubmitChanges();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"linq error {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't dc the datacontext on which you should call submit changes? That should be the unit of work container i think.

Comment: Thanks Dbuggy, I'm pretty sure I tried that way as well, with the same result. I tried                         dc.SubmitChanges(); and still nothing updated. I'm clearly missing something simple :/

Comment: Are you seeing there are updates taking place? What does the logging say ?

Comment: Off-topic, why do you open a connection? The context shouldn't need it. On-topic, you shouldn't work with the  `DataContext` class itself. You should create an inherited class of it that maps to your database tables, using the Visual Studio designer.

Comment: Seeing your predicament, also in comments below, I'd stick to ADO.Net for such a simple task. If you're doing more database processing you really should consider diving into Entity Framework. LINQ-to-SQL is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. My main issue with ado.net is updating tables based on a set of values. Sql is crap at handling arrays passes to it unless you do ugly stuff. I thought about EF but I don’t have direct Visual Studio access to the database. In order to test I have to deploy my compiles application to a remote machine that can connect to the Db.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should specify to the Entity Framework context, that the entity has changed, in order to update it.

```
...
k.StatusOfKey = (int)newState;
EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"New Key {k.ShowKeyAsJson()}");

dc.Entry(k).State = EntityState.Modified;
...
```

When you execute the SaveChanges() method, all your objects will be modified.

Comment: I tried this example, but I get DataContext does not contain a definition for Entry. As well as the name EntityState does not exist in the context.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? It is EF Core? My anwser is for EF 5. EF Core is different

Comment: I wasn't using EF as far as I'm aware. I was just using LINQ. I'm guessing I need to somehow incorporate EF if i want to update from the results of a linq query? :( Damn. I don't really want to add EF as a part of this project. Was hoping to use the flexibility of Linq alone.